# SpringBoot Nullpointer exception during api testing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I am trying to write tests for my rest controller and getting a `NullPointerException` whenever I attempt to perform actions on the `MockMvc` instance.

My project is structured as follows:

POJO:

```
@Entity
public class Pair {
    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String a;
    private String b;

    //getters and setters...

}
```

Rest Controller:

```
@RestController
public class PairController {

    @Autowired
    private PairServiceImpl pairService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pair", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public Pair addPair(String a, String b) {
        Pair newPair = new Pair();
        newPair.setA(a);
        newPair.setB(b);
        return pairService.addNewPair(newPair);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/pair", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Pair> getPairs() {
        return pairService.getPairs();
    }
}
```

Service layer:

```
@Service
public class PairServiceImpl implements PairService {
    @Autowired 
    private PairRepositoryImpl pairRepository;

    public Pair addNewPair(Pair newPair) {
        return pairRepository.save(newPair);
    }

    public List<Pair> getPairs() {
        return pairRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface PairRepositoryImpl extends JpaRepository<Pair, Long> {

}
```

And I want to test the PairController API endpoints:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {DemoApplication.class, DatabaseConfig.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {PairController.class})
public class PairControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private PairService pairService;

    @Test
    public void addPairTest() {
        Pair testPair = new Pair();
        testPair.setA("a");
        testPair.setB("b");
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        MvcResult mvcResult =      mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/pair").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(testPair))).andReturn();
        //The line above throws an exception
        int status = mvcResult.getResponse().getStatus();
        assertEquals(200, status);
    }
}
```

If I dont add the `@ContextConfiguration` the tests cannot find my endpoint. 
I tried to log the a and b value when the `addPair` method was invoked, and both values were `null`. You can also see that I add a custom database config class "`DatabaseConfig`", which contains a H2 embedded database datasource method such that the tests do not use the production database. The `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation is present in this class and it points to the repository shown above.

I have tried to juggle around many different annotations but they all have the same end result: null values in the controller method.

I have also tried to manually constructing the `MockMvc` instance using `@Autowired` on the WebApplicationContext and using that to initialize the `MockMvc` instance in a method with the `@Before` annotation - but the end result was the same.

I have made a comment below the line that throws an exception, located in the `PairControllerTests` class.

So if I run the application and test it using Postman and the production database the endpoints work and the data is persisted and retrieved properly. This issue only happens during testing.

Comment: What happens if you only leave `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` , `@SpringBootTest`  with no parameters and `@AutoConfigureMockMvc` in `PairControllerTests`?

Comment: I cannot connect to the database. I created a custom datasource for testing only purposes and I've only managed to use this datasource by mentioning it in the @SpringBootTest annotation

Comment: Can you double check your code? `return pairService.getPairs(l);`

Comment: That was a mistake, I must have put it my accident but it is not there in the source. That method does not take any parameters.

Comment: Did you consider removing the `(classes = {DemoApplication.class, DatabaseConfig.class})` from the annotation? Why limit it to those two classes? According to the annotation documentation: "If no explicit classes are defined the test will look for nested @Configuration classes, before falling back to a SpringBootConfiguration search".

Comment: So a @Configuration class within the test class?

Comment: `PairControllerTests` doesn't compile, please check.

Comment: remove `@SpringBootTest` and `@ContextConfiguration` annotations from your test